# Cambiar el BackColor de la Fila de un DataGridView cuando paso el mouse encima de dicha fila

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, datagrid

Bendiciones para todos Uds. Tengo un Datagridview en el cual muestro el contenido de una tabla, pero quisiera que cuando paso mi mouse por encima de una fila, dicha fila cambie de color, similar a la clase table-hover de bootstrap... he intentado hacerlo de esta forma, pero no me funciona.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
private void FrmCategoria_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{
    GridCategorias.RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.BlueViolet;  
}
```

También he probado con estos otros eventos:

Evento MouseHover:

```
private void FrmCategoria_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridCategorias.RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.BlueViolet;
}
```

Evento MouseLeave:

```
private void FrmCategoria_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridCategorias.RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.GreenYellow;
}
```

Quisiera que funcionara de la misma manera que funciona una tabla de bootstrap con la clase table-hover, solo que no se que es lo que no me funciona. (Los colores solo son una referencia)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

agradezco de antemano la ayuda que me puedan brindar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias por la Referencia **Leandro Tuttini**, me sirvió de mucho, y después de hacer muchas pruebas logré lo que quería.

- En el evento CellMouseEnter de mi DataGridView.

  ```
  private void GridCategorias_CellMouseEnter(object sender,DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
  {
      GridCategorias.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightCyan;
  }
  ```
- En el evento CellMouseLeave de mi DataGridView.

  ```
  private void GridCategorias_CellMouseLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)

  {
      GridCategorias.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Snow;
  }
  ```

finalmente este es el resultado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

El problema que noto con el codigo que usas es que asocias los eventos `MouseHover` y `MouseLeave` sobre el `FrmCategoria` en lugar de hacerlo sobre el `GridCategorias`

[Highlight the DataGridView row that is under the mouse in C#](http://csharphelper.com/blog/2017/03/highlight-the-datagridview-row-that-is-under-the-mouse-in-c/)

Analiza como utiliza

```
private int HighlightedRowIndex = -1;

private void dgvValues_CellMouseEnter(object sender,
    DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex == HighlightedRowIndex) return;

    if (HighlightedRowIndex >= 0)
    {
        SetRowStyle(dgvValues.Rows[HighlightedRowIndex], null);
    }

    HighlightedRowIndex = e.RowIndex;
    if (HighlightedRowIndex >= 0)
    {
        SetRowStyle(dgvValues.Rows[HighlightedRowIndex],
            HighlightStyle);
    }
}
```

Lo primer que debes notar es que usa el evento `CellMouseEnter` pero del `DataGridView`, para asi poder obtener el valor `e.RowIndex` y conocer que row debe resaltar

Tambien usa el evento `CellMouseLeave` para quitar el resaltada cuando se desplaza el mouse y se abandona la celda

```
private void dgvValues_CellMouseLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (HighlightedRowIndex >= 0)
    {
        SetRowStyle(dgvValues.Rows[HighlightedRowIndex], null);
        HighlightedRowIndex = -1;
    }
}
```

Usa la variable `HighlightedRowIndex` para conocer en todo momento sobre que row se esta desplazando

---

Tambien hay otra tecnica usando el evento `CellMouseMove`

```
private void dataGridView1_CellMouseMove(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{ 
   DataGridView1.ClearSelection();
   if (e.RowIndex > -1) { 
      DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Selected = true;  
   }         
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces en el movimiento vas limpiando la seleccion y volviendola asignar la la row sobre la cual se tenga posicionado el mouse en ese momento